# Python: How to return a string with a certain formatting for a nested list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, tostring, nested-lists

So I am trying to make a text-based adventure game, and it has a map system managed using a nested list, like so:

```
self.map_ = [
    ['O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O']
]
```

I have the map inside a class called `Map()` that has functions to create the map, add and change cells, and so on.

However, I am not sure how to print the map.  I would like to create a `__str__()` function to print the map, but I am unsure of how to do so.  I would like it to be printed out like this, with spaces separating the elements on the X axis and a line break separating the Y axis:

```
O O O
O O O
O O O
```

I have seen examples that look like this:

```
for row in map_:
    print ' '.join(row)
```

...and this example prints the map in exactly the format I would like.

However, I want to turn this into a `__str__()` function, where it returns a combination of `' '.join(row)` (printing a space between each row element) and `'\n'.join(map_)` (printing a newline between each row).

Of course, I would like the elements to be in the correct order (upper left on the printed view corresponds to `map_[0][0]` etc).

Is there a way I can do this with the `__str__()` function, or do I have to resort to using the printing function above?

Comment: You will have to create own class to use `__str__()`

Comment: Your `__str__` method needs to return the string you want, not print it.

Comment: @Pynchia: BLARGH! Stop using pointless `lambda`s, particularly to just turn around and call a C built-in that could be used directly: `'\n'.join(map(' '.join, self.map_))`. If you're using `lambda` with `map`, don't; it's slower and longer than a more Pythonic gen expr or list comp. Only time `map` wins meaningfully over list comp/gen expr is if the transform function is a C builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

```
"\n".join([" ".join(row) for row in map_])
```

For example:

```
In [1]: map_ = [
   ...:     ['O', 'O', 'O'],
   ...:     ['O', 'O', 'O'],
   ...:     ['O', 'O', 'O']
   ...: ]

In [2]: print "\n".join([" ".join(row) for row in map_])
O O O
O O O
O O O
```

And to more directly answer your question about using `__str__()`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join([" ".join(row) for row in self.map_])
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not at a computer right now but I will accept this answer if it works (which I assume it will).

Answer (score 1):

use space to join each row element, and use `\n` to join each row

```
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join([" ".join(x) for x in self.map_])
```

Comment: The '[]'s inside the call to `join` are unnecessary. They create a temporary list which is passed to `join`. If you leave them off, no list is created, and the inner generator expression will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly faster solution than the list comprehension approach, though it would only matter at all if the board sizes were huge:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(map(' '.join, self.map_))
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with a C built-in function (which `str.join` is) can beat an equivalent list comprehension by a decent margin by pushing more work to the C layer on the CPython reference interpreter.

Comment: The map won't be super big for now, but I might try this. Just a quick question though: What does map() do?

Comment: @jm13fire: Here's [the `map` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map); short version; it takes a mapping function and iterable(s) and returns a new `list` of the results of calling the mapping function with each of the input values as arguments. So in this case, `map(' '.join, self.map_)` is just an optimized version of `[' '.join(x) for x in self.map_]`; the optimization is because it caches the function once instead of loading it over and over and avoids executing Python byte code for each value. In Py3, it's almost the same, but it returns a generator, not a `list`.

Comment: @jm13fire: In general, `map` is something to only use in rare circumstances, specifically, when the transform function is a built-in implemented in C, and you *really* need the extra speed (and even then, it's usually only about a 10% savings over the list comprehension); if you ever consider using `map` with a `lambda` function or the like, stop, and use a list comprehension, which will be faster for that sort of scenario (by avoiding the need to call the function, the list comp just inlines the transform code directly).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        self.map_ = [
            ['O', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O']
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        string = ""
        for i in self.map_:
            for j in i:
                string += j + " "
            string += "\n"
        return string

    def change(self, x, y): # For change correctly invert the order
        self.map_[y][x] = "A" 

def main():
    mapa = Map()
    print(mapa)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```